# What is the difference between the Time and Mtime fields?

Tags: timestamp, bcoin

Could anybody please tell me the difference between these two fields?

- **time**
- **mtime**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

time is when the tx is confirmed in a block (the block timestamp) and mtime is the clock-on-the-wall timestamp when the node first sees the tx (aka "mempool" time)